# How to know magento 1.9 version Using MySql?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, version

I am having Magento1 Database details.
Using that can we get the version of Magento?

I found it can get with files or with some custom code. I am looking to get from the Database. In which table does it store the version?

Please, anyone, suggest the answer.

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: Please open this link here you get your solution https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-version/

Comment: Please read the question properly. I am trying to get it from mysql query. Is that possible?

Comment: same answer already given by @Rohan why you added again ?

Answer (score 3):

**`Magento 1.x`** does not save its version information in the database tables. Instead, its version is set in the **`app/Mage.php`** file.

Wherever it needs to show the Magento version, it calls **`Mage::getVersion()`** function, which is hardcoded in the **`app/Mage.php`** file.

Therefore, you will need to follow the same process.

Please let me know if anything is unclear in my answer.

Comment: I am clear about this. So we can't get the version of magento using DB connection string is it?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

> Directly from database its difficult but you can do with this trick

In magento database you will get `core_config_data` table

in that table you will get `base_url`

then hit that `baseUrl/downloader` in your browser.

if downloader is not secure in that site you will see login page and in that page you can see magento version

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways into this below link to check magento version. You can check using that :

https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-version/

Comment: Can you please read my question ? Can we get using mysql connection string?